# Install4j deletes response.varfile during rollback

Tags: java, install4j

During a rollback Install4j keeps deleting the response.varfile, even though the file was created by a previous installation.

The rollback is called after an action with "Failure Strategy" set to "Quit on failure" returns false.

How can I make sure that the response.varfile is kept after the rollback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This s a bug and will be fixed in 6.1.6, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build.